# Java Code - ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException

Tags: math

I have written the following code and keep running into this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at yournamep3.Yournamep3test.main(Yournamep3test.java:23)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Yournamep3test { 


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Check if target file exists
        File targetFile = new File(args[0]);


        try {

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(targetFile);
            out.write("\r\nStringed musical Instrument program");

            for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < 10; arrayIndex++) {

                out.write("\r\n\r\n");              
                out.write("\r\nCreating new Stringed Musical Instrument object now..............");
                Yournamep3 violinInstrument = new Yournamep3();

                violinInstrument.setNameOfInstrument("Violin # " + (arrayIndex+1));

                out.write("\r\nCreated instrument with name - "
                        + violinInstrument.getNameOfInstrument());

                int num = violinInstrument.getNumberOfStrings();
                out.write("\r\nNumber of strings in instrument is " + num);

                out.write("\r\nNames of String are ");
                String strings[] = violinInstrument.getStringNames();
                for (int counter = 0; counter < num; counter++) {
                    out.write("\r\n" + strings[counter]);
                }

                out.write("\r\nIs the Instrument playing - "
                        + violinInstrument.isPlaying());
                out.write("\r\nIs the Instrument tuned - "
                        + violinInstrument.isTuned());

                out.write("\r\nTuning now.........");

                violinInstrument.setTuned(true);
                out.write("\r\nIs the Instrument tuned - "
                        + violinInstrument.isTuned());

                out.write("\r\nCalling the Instrument play  method now..");
                violinInstrument.startPlayInstrument();
                out.write("\r\nIs the Instrument playing - "
                        + violinInstrument.isPlaying());



                out.write("\r\nStopping playing of instrument..............");
                violinInstrument.stopPlayInstrument();
                out.write("\r\nIs the Instrument playing - "
                        + violinInstrument.isPlaying());


            }
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I think the issue is with line 23.  Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

This is the other part of the code yournamep3

public class Yournamep3 {

```
//fields to determine if the instrument is isTuned,
private boolean isTuned;
```

//and if the instrument is currently isPlaying.
   private boolean isPlaying;

private String name;

private int numberOfStrings = 4; // number of strings
   private String nameofStringsInInstrument[] = {"E", "C", "D", "A"}; //an array of string names

```
//A constructor method that set the isTuned and currently isPlaying fields to false.
public Yournamep3() {
    this.isTuned = false;
    this.isPlaying = false;
}


/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getNameOfInstrument() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setNameOfInstrument(String nameOfInstrument) {
    this.name = nameOfInstrument;
}


// Other methods

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return isPlaying;
}

public void setPlaying(boolean playing) {
    this.isPlaying = playing;
}

public boolean isTuned() {
    return isTuned;
}

public void setTuned(boolean isTuned) {
    this.isTuned = isTuned;
}

public void startPlayInstrument() {
    System.out.println("The Instrument is now Playing.");
    isPlaying = true;
}

public void stopPlayInstrument() {
    System.out.println("The Instrument is not Playing anymore.");
    isPlaying = false;
}

public void startTuneInstrument() {
    System.out.println("The Instrument is Tuned.");
    isTuned = true;
}

public void stopTuneInstrument() {
    System.out.println("The Instrument is not Tuned.");
    isTuned = false;
}



public int getNumberOfStrings() {
   return this.numberOfStrings ;
}

public String[] getStringNames() {
    return nameofStringsInInstrument;
}
```

}

Comment: What does the message say?  You tried to access element zero (which would be the first element in the array), but there are no elements in the array at all.  (Of course, we have no idea where line 23 is, since you apparently removed some lines.)

Comment: My guess is that the error is on this line: `File targetFile = new File(args[0]);`, or on one of the lines you deleted.

Comment: You have lots of out.write(...) statements.  You should be able to narrow it down to a particular line of your code based on the last output line.

Comment: @womanamongmen - No need to "narrow it down" -- the exception tells you what line is in error.

Comment: `args` is an array that contains as many elements as there are separate words after `java Yournamep3test`.  If there are no words after that then there are zero elements and you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your getStringNames() method for your violinInstrument. It seems to me that it isn't populating your String array properly, or the getNumberOfStrings() method does not give the right number of strings. If you put the code for that up, I can help a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I have added the remainder of the code to the original posting.

Answer (score 0):

Line 23 appears to be

```
Yournamep3 violinInstrument = new Yournamep3();
```

If that's the case you should check the constructor for Yournamemp3

Since Line 23 is

```
File targetFile = new File(args [0]);
```

It indicates that your args object is empty. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException is thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. 0 is an illegal index.

Comment: If the error were in the constructor that would be at the top of the stack.

Comment: Hmm..may be so. It would help if OP provided what is the line number 23 on the editor she/he is using.

Comment: Line 23: File targetFile = new File(args [0]);

Comment: @user3697829 - As I expected.

Comment: Holmes' dictum -- when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.